# dns is fine but www don't work

Tags: networking, server, dns

I currently have a server with a static IP address and setup DNS on it.  I have my DNS server working correctly for my domain.  I can create an A or CNAME record, restart BInd9 and it works. I have only had a problem with my "www" record.  I have changed my zone file tons of times and it doesn't seem to work if I ping or go to www.mydomain.com.

Here is my zone file:

```
$TTL 14400
mydomain.com.      IN      SOA     mydomain.com.      randy.mydomain.com. (
        2013032600 ;Serial Number
        86400 ;refresh
        7200 ;retry
        3600000 ;expire
        86400 ;minimum
)

mydomain.com.      86400   IN      NS      ns1.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.      86400   IN      NS      ns2.mydomain.com.
mydomain.com.      14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
ro1                     14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
ns1                     14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
ns2                     14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
dev                     14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
randy                   14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
test1                           IN      CNAME   mydomain.com.
www                     14400   IN      A       1.2.3.4
```

I'm new at Bind but looked at a lot of what was in the DNS at my current webhost.
The records dev, test1, and randy I created and they worked as soon as I restarted Bind9.  I can ping "www.mydomain.com" from the server.  But not from outside.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you told the outside machines to use the 1.2.3.4 machine as the nameserver?  If your outside machines are still using DHCP then they will be looking to your router/hub for a DNS machine.

Hugs

Mandy